# Automate process during docker push

Tags: bash, docker

Can I add a hook that runs whenever I do a `docker push`?

I'm using docker for the first time, I have installed CLAIRCTL and I have success doing statics analysis by analyzing images manually and generating reports, but I want that to be automatic.

How can I do an automatic process to analyze all images every time there is a push of a new image to my registry, I had no idea to how to do this so i want to know if anyone here has done this before.

I'm looking for the secure way.

Comment: One easy way to do it is to write a wrapper around `docker push`, which does everything you want, and then calls push. You could name this `docker-push.sh`, for example.

Comment: I added a concise description (using standard terminology) at the top, and reworded a bit, so hopefully you get an answer more quickly.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the secure way," because security means different things to different people. If it's important to you, spell it out, and tell us exactly what you mean by "secure". (Secure from what? etc.)